# How can i dynamically load/play/pause multiple-source HTML5 audio on click? 

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, browser, html5-audio

I have a content slider, set to play / stop on each click.

The problem: I want it to pause on second click. Right now it won't pause. Any ideas?

See site here: http://dev.alsoknownas.ca/music/ (audio branding section on homepage).

Here's the code:

**Edited to reflect the code suggested by Lloyd below:

```
<audio id="player"></audio>
```

Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("span.1").attr("data-src","song.mp3");
$("span.2").attr("data-src","song2.mp3");
$("span.3").attr("data-src","song3.mp3");
$("span.4").attr("data-src","song4.mp3");
$("span.5").attr("data-src","song5.mp3");
});

$("span.1,span.2,span.3,span.4,span.5").click(function () {
  var player = document.getElementById("player");
  player.src = this.getAttribute("data-src");
  player.play();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this markup:

```
<audio id="player"></audio>

<span class="1">one</span>
<span class="2">two</span>
```

use this script:

```
$("span.1")
    .attr("data-src-mp3","song1.mp3")
    .attr("data-src-ogg","song1.ogg");
$("span.2")
    .attr("data-src-mp3","song2.mp3")
    .attr("data-src-ogg","song2.ogg");

$("span[data-src-mp3]").click(function () {
    var player = document.getElementById("player"),
        $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass("selected")) {
        if (player.paused) {
            player.play();
        } else {
            player.pause();
        }
    } 
    else {
        $("span[data-src-mp3].selected").removeClass("selected");
        $this.addClass("selected");
        $(player)
            .empty()
            .append($("<source>").attr("src", $this.attr("data-src-mp3")))
            .append($("<source>").attr("src", $this.attr("data-src-ogg")))
        player.play();
    }
});
```

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/75lb/8cGBx/

Comment: I think I didn't make my problem clear in my post, I've edited it to make more sense. Everything totally works except in order to pause, it requires a double click (probably something to do with the .bind at the top...

Comment: I understood the question. My answer gives you the functionality you need, without needing to click twice, with a much smaller amount of code.  If you weren't looking for a refactored solution, sorry - i'll look at it again once i get back to my computer.

Comment: I appreciate the response and the solution, looks like it would work! The only problem I'd have is the spans are created by a plugin script and I don't have direct access to them. I guess I could add a 'data-src' to each one through a script...

Comment: nah.. i'll alter the fiddle to work with your precise markup and get back to ya..

Comment: are the two `audio` elements added by plug-ins too? as we only ever play one media file at a time, it would make life much easier to stick with one `audio` tag

Comment: Lloyd, I've used your script, much simpler and better, thanks! Everything works except the pause at the moment. I'll update the code above to reflect the changes.

Comment: oh, ok - cool! well, i posted an alternative solution using your original markup too, if that helps.

Comment: ok, have posted a solution to pause audio on second click.. i implemented the 'selected' flag as a class so you could style the now-playing element, if necessary.

Comment: Works perfectly! You have no idea how much grief you've just solved. Fantastic solution!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7490/discussion-between-lloyd-and-sirwilliam85)

Comment: Perhaps you may want to `.empty` the player first since the `source` children are accumulating now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Instead of doing

```
$('audio').bind('play','pause', function() {
```

Do

```
$('audio').bind('play pause', function(event) {
```

According to your code, by default audio is paused, when user clicks, it starts playing, and on next click it pauses.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried it and unfortunately it doesn't seem to behave any differently. I'm assuming my problem is something to do with the use of the 'playing' variable.